# Redis connection failing

Tags: javascript, node.js, deployment, redis, docker

So I have node app docker containers running, and they run fine, but I noticed over the course of 1-2 months all of my apps begun having errors with redis, seems like the connection is not making it / is being refused. This is the error:

Error: Redis connection to xx.x.x.xxx:xxxx failed - connect ETIMEDOUT

I've noticed that I have a few idle connections, so it seems like there is something that is not properly closing itself. I have idle connections that are months old (a problem to fix as well), but Redis shouldn't fail if I have idle connections, I'm sure I haven't hit its limit.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Redis require some specific setup in its host machine, that is why it is very attached to a *"Redis ready Docker host machine"* when You try to use it in a docker container environment.

You should try to add this lines:

```
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_reuse = 1
net.ipv4.tcp_tw_recycle = 1
```

in Your docker host machines ***/etc/sysctl.conf*** file, that run redis containers.

Please let me know if it works.

Comment: What would this do? And how is it related to the redis connection dying?

Comment: Hi, connections are not dying, connections are failed. Not the same ;) . TCP TIME_WAIT state "allow the OS to quickly reuse TIME_WAIT TCP sockets". Please check this, maybe could help http://redis4you.com/articles.php?id=012&name=redis

Comment: You're saying connections are failing because it's waiting too long to close connections? I have connections that are months old, surely the TIME_WAIT can't be that long?